# Passing variables/parameters from subroutine-to-subroutine via script-file

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing

I want to pass a variables/parameters from one VBA subroutine (main) to another VBA subroutine through a "script (.vbs) file". While I understand that you can pass a variable/parameter via subroutine-to-subroutine by using the "call" command. For educational purposes, I want to pass it through a "script (.vbs) file". I want to learn how to pass a variable from the main subroutine to a "script file" and then from the "script file" to another subroutine. I have attached a simple source code to sum the values A and B. There is an error in the code and/or script; Somehow, the "SumProcess" subroutine's auguments are not receiving the correct values. Can anyone help or add codes to the one I have shown below? Much appreciated.

```
Sub Main()
Dim A, B As Integer
Dim AddString As String
     
   AddString = "Plus"
   AA = Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "A").Value    'Read A cell
   BB = Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "C").Value    'Read B cell
       
   SumTot "SumProcess", AddString, AA, BB
End Sub

Function SumTot(TargetSubroutine As String, AddString As String, AA As Integer, BB As Integer)
Dim ExcelPathName  As String
Dim ExcelNewFileName  As String

   ExcelPathName = "C:\temp\AddAB\"
   ExcelNewFileName = "AddAB_new"
   
   'Register new files (.xlsm and .vbs)
   Dim ExcelFilePathName As String: ExcelFilePathName = ExcelPathName + ExcelNewFileName + ".xlsm"
   TargetSubroutine = "'" + ExcelNewFileName + ".xlsm'!" + TargetSubroutine
   Dim VBScriptFilePathName As String: VBScriptFilePathName = ExcelPathName + ExcelNewFileName + ".vbs"
    
   'Create .xlsm file [if exist delete it and save master in its place]
   If IsFile(ExcelFilePathName) Then
      SetAttr ExcelFilePathName, vbNormal        'First remove ReadOnly attribute (if set)
      Kill ExcelFilePathName                     'Delete the duplicate .xlsm file
   End If
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ExcelFilePathName  'Make copy of Excel's master .xlsm file

   'Create script file. [If script exist delete it and create a new one]
   Dim fileSystem As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Dim writer As Scripting.TextStream
   With fileSystem
      If .FileExists(VBScriptFilePathName) Then
         .DeleteFile (VBScriptFilePathName) 
      End If
   End With
   Set writer = fileSystem.OpenTextFile(VBScriptFilePathName, ForWriting, True)
   
   'Open the script to write
   writer.WriteLine "Set ExcelApplication = CreateObject(""Excel.Application"")"
   writer.WriteLine "ExcelApplication.Visible = True"
   writer.WriteLine "Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(""" + ExcelFilePathName + """)"
      
   'Run target VBA program and close Excel workbook (write to script file)
   writer.WriteLine "ExcelWorkbook.Application.Run """ + TargetSubroutine + """, AddString, AA, BB"
   writer.WriteLine "ExcelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Close True"
   writer.WriteLine "ExcelApplication.Application.Quit"
  
   writer.Close
   Set writer = Nothing
   Set fileSystem = Nothing

   'Execute the script (run script file).
   Dim scriptingShell As Object: Set scriptingShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   scriptingShell.Run (VBScriptFilePathName)
   Set scriptingShell = Nothing
End Function

Sub SumProcess(ByVal AddString As String, ByVal AA As Integer, ByVal BB As Integer)
'Print the result in Excel's spreadsheet
Dim CC As Integer

   CC = AA + BB
   Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "B").Value = AddString
   Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "D").Value = CC
End Sub

Public Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if file exist.
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really odd thing to want to do but...

If you use `Set ExcelApplication = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` then you can attach to the currently-running Application and there's no need to save a copy of the workbook and spin up a separate application object.

```vb
Sub Main()
   Dim A As Integer, B As Integer, AddString As String
     
   AddString = "Plus"
   A = Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "A").Value    'Read A cell
   B = Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "C").Value    'Read B cell
       
   SumTot "SumProcess", AddString, A, B
End Sub

Function SumTot(TargetSubroutine As String, AddString As String, AA As Integer, BB As Integer)
    Const VBS = "C:\Tester\tmp.vbs"
    Const ForWriting = 2
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile(VBS, ForWriting, True)
        .WriteLine "Set ExcelApplication = GetObject(,""Excel.Application"")"
        .WriteLine "ExcelApplication.Run """ + TargetSubroutine + """, """ & AddString & """," & AA & "," & BB
        .Close
    End With
    VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run VBS
End Function

Sub SumProcess(ByVal AddString As String, ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "B").Value = AddString
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AplusB").Cells(2, "D").Value = A + B
End Sub
```

FYI you can skip the file for the vbscript and instead use a `ScriptControl` object:

```vba
Function SumTot(TargetSubroutine As String, AddString As String, AA As Integer, BB As Integer)
    With CreateObject("ScriptControl")
        .Language = "VBScript"
        .ExecuteStatement "Set ExcelApplication = GetObject(,""Excel.Application"")"
        .ExecuteStatement "ExcelApplication.Run """ & TargetSubroutine & """, """ & _
                              AddString & """," & AA & "," & BB
    End With
End Function
```

If you have problems running ScriptControl then see here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Registry-key-to-re-enable-835fba77